# Remove duplicate Digits form the given integer

Tags: java, arrays, integer, set

I have got my result based on below approach, but I'm not satisfied.

I want some other way and efficient manner to get the expected output.

*Input:*

```
112341
```

*Output:*

```
1234
```

No duplicates should be displayed in output and answer must be `1234`.

*My solution :*

```
public class PrintUnique {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = printUniquNums(112341);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static int printUniquNums(int num) {

        String nums =  Integer.toString(num);
        char [] ch = nums.toCharArray();
        Set<Character> store = new LinkedHashSet<>();

        String res = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++){
            if (store.add(ch[i])){
                res += ch[i];
            }
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(res);
    }
 }
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your approach. I can’t readily suggest anything better.

Comment: @OleV.V. I agree that any improvement will have a moderate effect, since a string representing an `int` would be at most `11` characters long. Nevertheless, creating of the array of characters via `toCharArray` for the purpose of iterating over the string is redundant. Similarly, `StringBuilder` can be used instead of generating `11` strings with string concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little tweaks with Java lambdas and streams. Your code is also good.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = printUniquNums(112341);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static int printUniquNums(int num) {

        String nums =  Integer.toString(num);
        List<String> digits = List.of(nums.split(""));
        Set<String> uniqueDigits = new HashSet<>();
        String uniqueNum = digits.stream().filter(uniqueDigits::add).reduce(String::concat).orElse(""); // set add method returns true if value not present
        return Integer.parseInt(uniqueNum);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, which doesn't use strings, implies to keep dividing the number by 10 to power the number's digits minus one and collect each digit from left to right in a `Set`, specifically a `LinkedHashSet` to maintain the insertion order. Then, using streams to rebuild the number without duplicate digits:

```
public static int uniqueNumber(int num) {
    int temp;
    Set<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    while (num > 10) {
        temp = (int) Math.pow(10, Math.ceil(Math.log10(num)) - 1);
        set.add(num / temp);
        num %= temp;
    }
    set.add(num);

    Integer[] digits = set.toArray(new Integer[set.size()]);
    return IntStream.range(0, digits.length)
            .map(i -> digits[i] * ((int) Math.pow(10, (digits.length - 1) - i)))
            .reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + b);
}
```

##### Output

```
1234
```

Here is a link to test the code:

https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/rSi

Answer (score 0):

This is not more effecient in term of performance. But its fewer lines of code and easier to read which in most cases is more important.

```
    private static int printUniquNums(int num) {
        TreeSet<String> tree= new TreeSet<>();
        for (char c : Integer.toString(num).toCharArray()) {
            tree.add(String.valueOf(c));
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(String.join("", tree));
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear in original problem statement, but if the order is significant then this code would give incorrect output. With input `2211` this code would produce `12` where possibly it should retain the position and produce output `21`.

Comment: it should maintain the insertion order as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your method can be reimplemented using *Stream API*.

One of the simplest ways to do it is to create a stream of *code points*.

Then we need to apply [`distinct()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#distinct()) to insure uniqueness of the stream elements. This operation utilizes a `LinkedHashSet` under the hood to reject duplicates and preserve the initial order.

And finally, apply a terminal operation [`collect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer)) by making use `StringBuilder` as a *container* for performing mutable reduction.

```
private static int printUniquNums(int num) {
    
    String result = String.valueOf(num).codePoints() // generating a stream of code points
        .distinct()                              // ensure uniqueness
        .collect(StringBuilder::new,             // mutable container
                 StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, // defining how values should be accumulated in the container
                 StringBuilder::append)          // how to merge the containers obtained while executing the stream in parallel
        .toString();
    
    return Integer.parseInt(result);
}
```

Another way of achieving this is to *map* stream elements into `String` type and make use of the built-in *collector* `joning()` that will take care of the stream concatenation for as:

```
private static int printUniquNums(int num) {
    
    String result = String.valueOf(num).codePoints() // generating a stream of code points
        .distinct()                      // ensure uniqueness
        .map(Character::getNumericValue) // getting a numeric value from a code point
        .mapToObj(String::valueOf)       // creating a single-character string
        .collect(Collectors.joining());  // combining the strings together
    
    return Integer.parseInt(result);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int result = printUniquNums(112341);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

*Output* (for both solutions):

```
1234
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/rSk)